# How to get google search page html code using python?

Tags: python, google-search, python-requests-html

I try to extract the google search page HTML code in python. I use `requests` module in python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+google+search+page+source+code+by+python"

resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
search = soup.find_all('div',class_="yuRUbf")
print(search)
```

But I can't find any of this `class_="yuRUbf"` in the code. I think it do not give me the source code. Now how can I do this work.

I also used `resp.content` but it didn't work.
I also `selenium` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SelectorGadget](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/#SelectorGadgetChromeExtension) Chrome extension to easily get CSS selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser (*not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript*).

To collect information from all pages you can use [non-token pagination](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#74dc)  with `while True` loop. The while loop is an endless loop, the exit from which in our case is the presence of a switch button to the next page, namely the CSS selector ".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]":

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
else:
    break
```

Also you can exit the loop by using the limit on the number of search pages:

```py
if page_num == page_limit:
   break
```

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-google-search-results-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

query = "how to get google search page source code by python"

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": query,          # query example
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "uk",          # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_limit = 5           # page limit
page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
        try:
           snippet = result.select_one(".lEBKkf span").text
        except:
           snippet = None
        links = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
      
        data.append({
          "title": title,
          "snippet": snippet,
          "links": links
        })

    if page_num == page_limit:
        break
    if soup.select_one(".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]"):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "How To Build a Website With Python - Digital.com",
    "snippet": "Examples of Sites Created Using Python · Google: The most popular search engine in the world uses Python · Instagram: Python was used to create the backend of ...",
    "links": "https://digital.com/how-to-create-a-website/with-python/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Google Search Operators: 40 Commands to Know in 2023 ...",
    "snippet": "30 Mar 2022 — ",
    "links": "https://kinsta.com/blog/google-search-operators/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Python From Scratch: Create a Dynamic Website - Code",
    "snippet": "19 Feb 2022 — ",
    "links": "https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/python-from-scratch-create-a-dynamic-website--net-22787"
  },
  {
    "title": "How to Use Python to Analyze Google Search Results at Scale",
    "snippet": "21 Dec 2020 — ",
    "links": "https://www.semrush.com/blog/analyzing-search-engine-results-pages/"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

Or you can also use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

query = "how to get google search page source code by python"
params = {
  "api_key": "...",                # serpapi key
  "engine": "google",              # serpapi parser engine
  "q": query,                      # search query
  "num": "100"                     # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "snippet": result.get("snippet"),
            "link": result.get("link")
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "How To Work with Web Data Using Requests and Beautiful ...",
    "snippet": "This tutorial will go over how to work with the Requests and Beautiful Soup Python packages in order to make use of data from web pages.",
    "link": "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-web-data-using-requests-and-beautiful-soup-with-python-3"
  },
  {
    "title": "google search - Simply Python",
    "snippet": "I have included part of the code for the noun phrase detection (Under pattern_parsing.py). ... Run google search and obtain page source for the images.",
    "link": "https://simply-python.com/tag/google-search/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Web Scraping Using Selenium Python - Analytics Vidhya",
    "snippet": "Step 2 – Install Chrome Driver · Step 2 – Install Chrome Driver · Step 3 – Specify search URL",
    "link": "https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/web-scraping-selenium-with-python/"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

There's a [13 ways to scrape any public data from any website](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/) blog post if you want to know more about website scraping.

Comment: it shows recaptcha. How can I overcame recaptcha.

Comment: To bypass the block you can try to use: [rotate user agents](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotateuser-agents), [captcha solver (2captcha)](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#captchasolver), [proxies + proxies rotation](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#proxies) or using API as in the example.